# Laravel : array_push not working in collection->each() iterator

Tags: laravel, collections, each, array-push

I have grouped collection and I iterate it using each() function.Inside the each function I want to add element to some array.But it is not working.Any idea?

```
$dataSet1 = [];

$appointments = [
         ['department' => 'finance', 'product' => 'Chair'],
         ['department' => 'marketing', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
         ['department' => 'finance', 'product' => 'Desk'],
]; 
$groupData = collect($appointments)->groupBy('department');

$groupData->each(function ($item, $key) {
   Log::info($key); //Show correct output in log
   array_push($dataSet1, $key); //ERROR
   array_push($dataSet1, 'A');//ERROR
});
```

Laravel version : 8.35.1

Comment: What would the `//ERROR`s be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the array to the function with `use`:

```php
$groupData->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$dataSet1) {
   Log::info($key); //Show correct output in log
   array_push($dataSet1, $key); //ERROR
   array_push($dataSet1, 'A');//ERROR
});
```

Pass-by-reference (`&`) is needed as long as `$dataSet1` is not an object instance.

Comment: Be aware that arrow functions, i.e. the shorthand `fn` syntax, do not modify the variables from outer scope as stated in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) (see Example #4). It will work though if you're modifying an object since it's always passed by reference.